# PHP - Call a function from a link\button

Tags: php, html, function

I know that PHP is only server-side and it's impossible to call directly a `PHP-FUNCTION` from a link.

But I can't use JavaScript \ jQuery \ Ajax

This is my code in `main.php`

```
function refreshgt2(){
    for($l=1; $l!=$max_cicle; ++$l ) {
        $data->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`name1`,`name1`,`anothername`,`dog`) VALUES ('ME','".$img[$l]."','".$l."','".$hello[$l]."')");        
    }       
}
```

And the html,

```
<a href="#" >Do something</a>
```

I've just tried with this [need a button that calls a php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049534/need-a-button-that-calls-a-php-function) but didn't work for me.

Someone can help me?

I need something that load the function only when I will press the link\button\image

Comment: So why can't you use Ajax? Is the php not the same origin?Even though you can try request via jsonp, like `xxx.php?callback=cb&param=abc`.

Comment: My link is: http://localhost/index.php?opz=zen the index.php call zen.php and zen.php call main.php. In this case a can use ajax?

Comment: Of course you can, you just need an ajax request, `zen.php` in this case.And it returns json/xml data, and you get it and invoke js function.As for `zen.php` calls `main.php`, that's server-side matter, `require_once('main.php')` ,run the function/method, and return result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work. it gives a button, support multiple function call and is pure php + html

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="function" value="refreshgt2">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if($_POST!=null && array_key_exists('function', $_POST)){
    if(strcasecmp($_POST['function'],'refreshgt2')==0){
        for($l=1; $l!=$max_cicle; ++$l )
        {
            $data->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`name1`,`name1`,`anothername`,`dog`) VALUES ('ME','".$img[$l]."','".$l."','".$hello[$l]."')");        
        }
    }else if(strcasecmp($_POST['function'],'some_other_function')==0){
        //do things
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i cant's use a javascript\jquery\ajax

Then the answer is `No`, you can not. Only option is to link your button to a new page which will generate the PHP output. PHP itself does not know anything about what you do at client side and whether you have clicked a link, PHP functions cannot execute at that time since PHP has already done its job and gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind a redirect

`<a href="your_php_script.php" >Do something</a>`

**you_php_script.php**

```
<?php

refreshgt2();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use javascript/ajax (why not? we are in 2013), you can't refresh part of the page on the fly. Your only chance is to call a page like

```
<a href="my-script.php">Do something</a>
```

and `my-script.php` then renders the page again after doing some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use querystrings, set the `href` in your html to point to your page, and add a querystring parameter so that your php can decide which function to execute:

HTML

```
<a href='main.php?fn=some_function'>Do something<a/>
```

PHP

```
switch($_GET['fn']) {
case 'some_function':
    //call your function 
    break;
default:
    //Handle this
}
```

Otherwise, redirect to another php script like the other answers mentioned.